# SELECT STATEMENT that exclude duplicate row that has different ID (Auto-increment) in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, duplicates

I have a table that has a lot of columns (about 30+), It has one Primary ID column which is auto-increments. Recently, I found out that it has a lot of duplicate rows, (All value in every cells are the same, except the Primary ID column).

How do I create a SQL SELECT statement that automatically exclude duplicate rows (I still need to keep the ID column)?

For Ex:

```
PK     Col1     Col2
1        A        B
2        A        B
3        C        C
4        C        C
```

I want a SELECT SQL that will return:

```
PK     Col1     Col2
1        A        B
4        C        C
```

Thanks All.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the lowest `pk` for every duplicate entry then you can use `min()`

```
select min(pk), col1, col2
from your_table
group by col1, col2
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can include every column except some certain column? Such as "SELECT * [EXCEPT Column_X] From TABLE_Y"

Comment: No, there is not. BTW an even better way would be **deleting** the duplicates once and fixing the code where the duplicates get inserted.